# Jetty, Maven plugin - how to configure default document?

Tags: java, maven-2, jetty, war, default-document

We're using Jetty 6.x, and Maven-2.

Anybody knows how to configure the default document?

I mean - there's a default that serves `/index.html` or any of it's equivalents when accessing the application root (browse to `/`).

And there should be a settings to control that.
(there is in tomcat and in IIS for example...)

**So 1 - how do I tell it to Jetty?**

I know the Jetty guys are proud in letting almost everything to be configured - there has to be a way to do that, it's just a problem of a poor documentation, that's what my instinct tells me.

**And 2 - how do I do that using Maven plugin ?**

This is actually a "bonus" question, if you only tell me how to do it with Jetty - I hope'll find eventually how to do it with Maven too. But in case anybody knows - it will be a great help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found it.
It has nothing to do with `Jetty` or `Maven`, although I'm sure that Jetty can provide it's own overrider configuration or defaults or something.

It was hard to find because they don't call it **default document**, but **welcome-files**.
It's a part of the JSP Servlet deffinitions, and is working with the file:  `/META-INF/web.xml`

And here's what needs to be inside

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">


<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>customDefaultDocument.html</welcome-file> 
</welcome-file-list>


</web-app>
```